# Running the animate package documentation

Tags: errors, documentation, animations, animate

I downloaded the tex file for the documentation of `animate` package by Alexander Grahn and tried to run it on MikTeX instead of giving me the PDF output it generate the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Please use LaTeX to compile this documentation.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.46   \makeatother
```

Kindly let me know how can I fix this.

Comment: What command did MikTeX run? Did it do pdflatex or latex or...?

Comment: It did pdflatex

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile it using latex and not pdflatex. You'll get a `.dvi` file that now you can convert to `.ps` using `dvips <file>.dvi`; then you can use `ps2pdf <file>.ps` to obtain a `.pdf` file. Your editor probably has an output profile (`LaTeX=>PS=>PDF` in the case of TeXnicCenter) that can help you to automate this process.

Comment: Any idea why it needs DVI output? The package seems to support `pdflatex`: "Package ‘animate’ supports the usual PDF making workflows, i. e. pdfLATEX,
LATEX ! dvips ! ps2pdf/Distiller and (X E)LATEX ! (x)dvipdfmx.".

Comment: BTW: Also I personally would have phrased the error message differently, because I count `pdflatex` to LaTeX, which is more a collective term. (Not that I blame that on you, Gonzalo)

Comment: @Martin: the package supports `pdflatex`, but the file `animate.tex` (which I assume was the file that Scientist tried to compile) uses PS-Tricks (`\usepackage{pst-3dplot}`), so it requires latex for its compilation.

Comment: @Martin: I will improve the message text in the source file

Comment: @Alexander: Thanks. It's not a big thing but can be confusing. Even having it in lowercase would make it clearer, i.e. 'latex' instead of LaTeX.